# Netty Channel bootstrap with pre-created ServerSocket

Tags: sockets, netty, bootstrapping

Currently you can bootstrap Netty with SocketAddress to create a channel factory. In order to do tight integration with JBoss AS7 and use its managed socket binding, I have a need where I need to use already created ServerSocket in bootstrapping the Netty channel factory. Is that possible? I did not find any relevant APIs.

I am trying to solve https://community.jboss.org/thread/203485

If not can I request that as a feature?

Answer (score 0):

In 4.x you will be able to create a Netty Channel from an existing NIO Channel. Is that what you are looking for:

https://netty.io/Documentation/New+and+Noteworthy#HAbilitytocreateaChannelfromanexistingJDKsocket

Be aware that Netty 4 is still in Alpha state..